# CoffeeScript in Rails toggle div based on Collection Select

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

I have a Rails app using a somewhat basic form and I need some help with some coffeescript.  Here is an excerpt of my form code:

```
  <%= f.label :Patient_Insurance, "Patient Insurance", class: "control-label" %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:insurance_id, Insurance.order("insurance_type ASC"), :id, :insurance_type, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select'}) %></br>
  <div id="medicaid_fax_number">
      <%= f.label :medicaid_fax_number %>
      <%= f.text_field :medicaid_fax_number, placeholder: '2812224444' %>
  </div>
```

What I want to happen is to keep the `medicaid_fax_number` field always hidden unless a user chooses "Medicaid" from the collection_select, then display the div.

I am really rusty on JS and Coffee script so I could really use a hand with this one.  I know that the thing I'm watching to change is the `call_insurance_id` (which is the ID in the form for the insurance collection select).  But I'm not sure in coffeescript how to evaluate whether or not the value is equal to "Medicaid".

I'll continue to do some more research and keep working at it, but I figured someone here more knowledgeable than I could help.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic solution, after you add to your Insurance model a column like "need_medicaid_fax_number" with type is boolean. You can update by the way below:

**.erb**

```
<%= f.label :Patient_Insurance, "Patient Insurance", class: "control-label" %>
<%= f.select :insurance_id, {include_blank: "Select"}, class: "select" do %>
  <%= options_for_select(Insurance.order("insurance_type ASC").map {|k, v| [k.insurance_type.humanize, k.id, {show_medicaid_fax_number: k.need_medicaid_fax_number?}]}, f.object.insurance_id, )%>
<%= end %>
</br>
<div id="medicaid_fax_number">
    <%= f.label :medicaid_fax_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :medicaid_fax_number, placeholder: 'Fax number' %>
</div>
```

**.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('#call_insurance_id').change ->
    option = $(this).find('option:selected')
    if option.attr("show_medicaid_fax_number") is "true"
      $('#medicaid_fax_number').show()
    else
      $('#medicaid_fax_number').hide()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but this didn't work for me.  I did a Chrome inspection and didn't see errors in the console so I'm not sure what the problem is.  See the answer I'm posting to what I got to work.  It evaluates off of the ID of the Insurance but I want to evaluate off the String "Medicaid".  Let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $ ->
  $('#call_insurance_id').change ->
    if $(this).val() is "12"
      $('#medicaid_fax_number').show()
    else
      $('#medicaid_fax_number').hide()
```

This works perfectly, however I have to hardcode the ID of the Insurance type into CoffeeScript.  I'd really like to be able to evaluated based on the string "Medicaid".  Can anyone help?